# making greedy algorithm work for every input

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote a code for greedy algorithm of cs50. It works for inputs between 0 and 1. How can I make it work to inputs like 4.2 , 6.5 , 8 etc?. I have listed my code below. What should I modify in the program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int count , change;
    float cents;
    printf("Enter the change amount : ");
    cents = GetFloat();
    cents = cents * 100;
    change = round(cents);
    count = 0;

    while(cents < 0 )
    {
        printf("Enter a positive number : ");
        cents = GetFloat();
    }

    while (change >= 25)
    {
        change = change - 25;
        count++;
    }

    while (change < 25 & change >= 10)
    {
        change = change - 10;
        count++;
    }
    while (change < 10 & change >= 5)
    {
        change = change - 5;
        count++;
    }
    while (change < 5 & change >= 1)
    {
        change = change - 1;
        count++;
    }

    printf("Total number of coins used : " );
    printf (" %d " ,  count );
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: A little more information would be nice. What is the program supposed to do? How does it behave with an input of 4.2? How should it behave? How have you tried to fix it so far?

Comment: `printf("Enter a positive number : "); cents = GetFloat();` need update `change`.

Comment: What are the output expected to do when input is 4.2?

Comment: The program is supposed to return minimum number of coins for a change. For example if I am to receive change of 75 cents then I would input 0.75 and since 25cents + 25 cents + 25 cents is equal to 75 cents, it will return 3 coins. It works in same way to all numbers between 0 and 1. If I input 2.5 it should only take care of 0.5 that is it should return 2 coins, since two quarters make 0.5 cents. But, it returns 10 instead. When I input 4.2 it should discard 4 and take 0.2 which is 20 cents and return 2 coins since two dimes make 20cents. But it returns 18.

Comment: This is not really a greedy algorithm, because there is always a discernible best answer.

Comment: First, you need to pull in the 100 if change >= 100. (4 does not have a process to discard.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you are using bitwise logical operators. You should use `&&` in your comparisons to compare the values of two expressions. There are other little issues: The loop that guarantees positive input should multiply `cents` by 100 and `round()`, before assigning this new value to change. But you don't actually need both `change` and `cents`. And you don't need as many comparisons as you have written, and without the extra comparisons, you don't need the logical operators that were causing you trouble in the first place!

### Edit

I noticed that a number like `4.20` was being rounded first, then multiplied by 100! Of course this is wrong, giving the same results for `4.20`, `4.75`, and `4`. I changed the code below accordingly, but your original code was doing this part correctly (except in the input validation loop, as mentioned earlier). Now the program correctly handle such inputs.

Here is a cleaned-up version (I don't have the `cs50.h` library, so there are some small differences):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int count;
    float cents;

    printf("Enter the change amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &cents);
    cents = (float)round(cents * 100);
    count = 0;

    while (cents < 0) {
        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
        cents = (float)round(cents * 100);
    }

    while (cents >= 25) {
        cents -= 25;
        count++;
    }
    while (cents >= 10) {
        cents -= 10;
        count++;
    }
    while (cents >= 5) {
        cents -= 5;
        count++;
    }
    while (cents >= 1) {
        cents -= 1;
        count++;
    }

    printf("Total number of coins used: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jay Jay-- you should see the Edit to the code in my answer. It now handles numbers with fractional parts correctly.